# jquery - how to find a span containing text withing another span

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

i have `span` containing text 'Compare'. within it I have another span containing 'Exam'.

I can grab each one separately:

```
$('span:contains("Compering")')
[<span class=​"prop">​…​</span>​] # works
```

other one:

```
$('span:contains("Exam")')
[<span class=​"prop">​…​</span>, ....​] #works
```

the thing is The second condition catches too many items , so I want to grab a span within a span.

**Update:** tried:

```
$('span:contains("Compering")').find('span:contains("Exam")')
[]
```

any ideas?

**edit**

found the bug in my question
The span is not contained inside the other span but inside the 'compering' span parent li. 
solved it by `$('span:contains("Compering")').closest('li').find('span:contains("Exam")')`
thanks @Praveen Kumar

Comment: Is `$('span:contains("Compering")')` a question typo?  Should it be `$('span:contains("Comparing")')`?

Comment: @JohnC Compering is a valid word. Don't worry. What the OP says is right. I solved it. `:)`

Comment: Kindly check my updated answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes compering is a valid word though I suspect it might be the wrong one in this case (though I suppose we'd need to see the `span` to be sure).

Comment: @JohnC No no... I understand your point. Check my answer, it is indeed not working because, `.find()` searches inside the spans and not the spans themselves. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar that's fine, I doubted it was the problem, I just asked the question because the OP said `i have span containing text 'Compare'` but then in their code they had `$('span:contains("Compering")')` which is talking about something else.

Comment: @JohnC Ha ha. Bulls eye man. I didn't see that. LoL. You are right. Accepted! `:P`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.filter()` by chaining:

```
$('span:contains("Compering")').filter('span:contains("Exam")')
```

The `.find()` doesn't work in this case, because it tries to search inside the matched elements, not the matched elements itself. `:)`

The `$` searches everywhere and the `.filter()` searches in the matched results.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $('span:contains("Compering")').filter('span:contains("Exam")').css("background", "#ccf");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<span class="prop">English Exam</span><br>
<span class="prop">Maths Exam</span><br>
<span class="prop">Compering Exam</span><br>
<span class="prop">Physics Exam</span><br>
<span class="prop">Computer Exam</span>
```

**Output: http://output.jsbin.com/joyawemaja**

**Update:**

According to OP's current set-up of HTML, the working code will be:

```
$('span:contains("Compering")').closest('li').find('span:contains("Exam")')
```

This is because, the `<span>`s are found in different `<div>`s.

Comment: @WebQube Kindly show your HTML also, so that we can play around. `:)`

Comment: @WebQube Thanks. Corrected the answer. You need to use `.filter()` and not `.find()`.

Comment: hi, found out my error: The span is not contained inside the other div. solved it by `$('span:contains("Compering")').closest('li').find('span:contains("Exam")')`

Comment: @WebQube LoL. Also `.find()` doesn't search for the local items.

Comment: please add my solution with parent 'li' and i'll accept

Comment: @WebQube Oh yeah, definitely no problem.

Comment: @WebQube Yay! Done! `:D`

Comment: @PraveenKumar : you said .find() doesn't search for the local items ...can you please explain on this ... and what exactly is local items...if you dont mind

Comment: @YoYo You wanna come to Chat?

Comment: @YoYo BTW can you understand this: The `.find()` doesn't work in this case, because it tries to search inside the matched elements, not the matched elements itself. `:)` We need to " "filter" out the matched elements, but `find` is concerned about the contents of those.

Comment: okay than can this work `$('span:contains("Compering")').parent().find('span:contains("Exam")')`   ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102219/discussion-between-yo-yo-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score -2):

```
var count = 0;
$('span:contains("Compering")').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('Exam') > -1) {
        count++;
    }
});
alert(count);
```

If you need to operate on each of the elements

Comment: How does it even solve it? You are mixing both jQuery and pure JS and making your code less efficient.

Comment: The problem is, already jQuery has loops in it, but you are introducing more, which is not good. Do you understand, see how my answer handles this same situation.

Comment: i follow your twitter